# What documents do I need to be allowed to leave the Phillipines if I already have a UK entry clearance?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, filipino-citizens

I would like to ask what documents I need to present to a Philippines IO to be sure I am allowed to leave the Philippines. (I am concerned about [offloading](https://www.rappler.com/life-and-style/travel/98629-offloading-travel-preparation-tips), which happens to some people leaving the Philippines.) I already have a UK tourist visa and this trip is sponsored by my boyfriend.

Comment: I assume you're traveling from the Philippines to the UK? Are you worried about entering the UK or being allowed to leave the Philippines?

Comment: I am more worried about being allowed to leave the Philippines.

Comment: @MarkCabilinCoralde Why would the Filipino officers not let you leave? They have no authority when it comes to rules in the UK

Comment: @Coke ["Offloading"](https://www.rappler.com/life-and-style/travel/98629-offloading-travel-preparation-tips) is a thing in the Philippines, in which their immigration officers decide if you're allowed to leave.

Comment: @ZachLipton Based on what would they refuse you exit?

Comment: @Coke I'm far from an expert on this topic, and a search for "offloading Philippines" (officially, "deferred departure") will give you more of an idea, though [this article](http://smalltowngirlsmidnighttrains.com/2016/08/04/anti-offloading-tips-immigration-officer/) gives some examples of the criteria that gets people referred to secondary. It appears to be intended to look for signs of human trafficking or illegal work, though the system has been described as "[indiscriminate](https://www.rappler.com/nation/100913-bureau-immigration-offloading-us-human-trafficking-report)" in its vagueness.

Comment: @ZachLipton Oh wow, don't get why the Philippines would care about what immigration violations their own citizens commit abroad.

Comment: @Coke A fair question. The stated intent is to protect their citizens from exploitation, but it seems to pose issues. I wish we had more of an expert on the topic at t.se, because it comes up with some regularity here, and even some people well versed in immigration issues haven't heard of it.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, a visa is a pre-approval for entry, so unless the UK officers suspect a change of circumstances or fraud on your part in obtaining the visa, the check will be swift.

To be safe, you could bring a return flight confirmation, but anything else is superfluous given that you hold a visa.

**UPDATE**: you say you're so desperate to stay in the UK for 5 months that you quit your job. That could well be classified as a material change of circumstances if it comes to light during the landing interview, and to be honest with you, if I was a UK officer I'd at least be very careful about letting you in. Because quitting a job just to stay with a boyfriend for 5 months...that's usually what you do if wanting to illegally immigrate in order to live with your partner.

Furthermore, make sure you don't stay longer than you declared on your visa application, as visa officers ***will*** have access to this info and staying significantly longer than declared could make it harder for you to get a visa next time.

Bring any and all documentation you can proving why you must return to the Philippines. Anything proving ties to your home country, in case you're asked for it.

Comment: Yes I have a return flight to the Philippines.and I also have all the photo copies of the documents that we have submitted when I have applied the Visa. The only circumtances that have changed is that I was still employed when I have applied for a visa and since work would not allow me to leave for 5 months I was forced to resigned since the visa was granted to me was 6 months. Would that be a problem in IO in UK and in the Philippines? hence that my boyfriend send mo a huge amount of money so that I can afford my travel

Comment: "I also have all the photo copies of the documents that we have submitted when I have applied the Visa" You don't need that; that's for people travelling visa-free. "Would that be a problem in IO in UK and in the Philippines?" The Philippines officers have no say in UK Immigration law - they will just check that your passport is valid and that you don't have an arrest warrant you're trying to escape.

Comment: @MarkCabilinCoralde As for the UK, actually it **could** be a red flag that you were so desperate to get to the UK for 5 months that you were willing to quit your job. You usually only do that if considering illegally immigrating. Be prepared to answer the question "why would I return after having quit the job just for a Long Uk Holiday?"

Comment: @MarkCabilinCoralde Hold up a second. You say the visa that was granted to you was 6 months (as is fairly typical), but how long did you tell the UK authorities you were visiting for when you applied for your visa? If you didn't tell them on your visa application that you were visiting for 5 months, that's a significant problem.

Comment: This answer really is not correct for this scenario, based on the links in Zach's comment. The airline check in desk will check your visa or other documents because they might get fined if they fly you to the UK when you don't have correct documents, but the Philippine government is trying to protect its citizens from trafficking by checking that they are legitimate travelers, at passport control desk.